# Flickering button on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gofer formed with images (link is below) and I have to change images when I hover over an image of gofer, and when images are changed it has to appear as a button.

But when I try to go on button it starts to flicker - I don't know how to make it stay the same way when it's just hover on image

My js code is:

```
function resetHex() {
        jQuery('#img1').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/init/1.png");
        jQuery('#hex1').removeClass('cont-image1');
        jQuery('#hex1 a.text-image1').remove();
        jQuery('#hex1 a:last').remove();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    //change images, hover first
    jQuery('.hexagon-container #hex1')
        .mouseover(function(){
        jQuery('#hex1').addClass('cont-image1').append('<a id="ti1" class="text-image1" href="/contact-us">buton<a>');
        jQuery('#img1').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/1.png");
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img2').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/2.png");
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img3').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/3.png");
        }, 200);
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img4').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/4.png");
        }, 300);
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img5').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/5.png");
        }, 400);
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img6').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/6.png");
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#img7').attr("src", "/themes/transformer/img/home/set1/7.png");
        }, 600);
    })
        .mouseout(function() {
            resetHex();
        });
```

My CSS code:

```
.cont-image1 .text-image1{
    background: #fd5b08 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;   
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Museo300;
    font-size: 13px; 
    padding: 4px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
}
.cont-image1 .text-image1{
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 35%;
}
```

http://lenspace.nexloc.com/
Thank you. Sorry for my English

Comment: Where is that button in the link? please post proper link

Comment: Try using the [hoverIntent jQuery Plug-in](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use preventDefault() on your functions as:

```
 .mouseover(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#hex1').addClass('cont-image1').append('<a id="ti1" class="text-image1" href="/contact-us">buton<a>');
```

Still I would recommend you to use css for changing images on mousehover

Comment: I tried that, but i didn't had any results. Because every line it's a div, and the first 2 imgs are in one div, next 3 in another one and the last 2 another one

Answer (score 0):

What might happen here is that when you create the button, it considers that the mouse does not hover the div anymore, because it now hovers the button instead. You can either:

- use jquery mouseenter and mouseleave events (should trigger only when you pass the div bounds)
- detect the button hover and prevent resetHex if it hovers the button inside the div

Comment: i was just wondering how you solved that ^^ this is going to be more complex; first solution i see is to use `<map>` and `<area>` elements. You can have one single map and define the areas of each heaxagon. Or use a already built plugin if this seems tto much work.. i'll see that when i have more time

Comment: It's true that it's not perfect, because for ex mouseenter is on div that is square, and my images are hexa, and the other images will change when i enter on div...But for the moment it's ok